# Space between \cline in table

Tags: tables

I'm working on a table with underlined headings, where each heading spans over two columns.

I'm trying to understand how to use the `\extracolsep` function to create space between the lines for every second coloumn.

Can someone help?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Price model effects}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}

\hline\hline

             &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Residual waste}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Plastic}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Paper}} \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{5-6} \cline{6-7}

            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kg per capita}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kg per capita}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Kg per capita}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ratio}\\
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Consider wswitching to the `booktabs` packages and its special lines, they have much better build in spacing.

Answer (score 5):

Using `\extracolsep` doesn't make much sense when using a `tabular` environment. You should be using a `tabular*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}  % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    %% \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} for a more open "look"
    \caption{Price model effects}

    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{6}{c}}

    \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Residual waste} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Plastic} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Paper} \\ 
    \cline{1-2} \cline{3-4} \cline{5-6} 
    Kg per capita & Ratio & 
    Kg per capita & Ratio & 
    Kg per capita & Ratio \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cmidrule` from the *booktabs* package.  It has argument *trim* which allows you to make the line slightly shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll ll ll}
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Residual waste} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Plastic} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Paper} \\ 
      \cmidrule(lr){1-2}  % trim from left/right
      \cmidrule(lr){3-4}  % note: in parenthesis, not brackets
      \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
    Kg per capita & Ratio & 
    Kg per capita & Ratio & 
    Kg per capita & Ratio \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

This will give you

[image]

Obviously, you can use other packages to fine-tune the look.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.